# Zero-dimensional matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, idiomatic-usage

In a recent *Mathematica* project, $(n \times 0)$- and $(0 \times n)$-dimensional matrices have suddenly become a frustratingly common edge case for me.  For instance, consider the following two situations, both common in linear algebra programming:

1. Suppose we have a matrix $A$, presenting a linear transformation $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\R^n \to \R^m$.  The kernel of $A$ is a particular subspace of the source, $\R^n$, and if $A$ has a kernel of dimension $d > 0$, then `NullSpace[A]` produces a new matrix presenting a map $\R^d \to \R^n$ whose image is $\ker A$.  This mode of thought is very useful; it lets you, for instance, restrict the action of some other map $B: \R^n \to \R^l$ to the kernel of $A$ by multiplication: `B.Transpose[NullSpace[A]]`.
2. Suppose we have a pair of matrices $A$ and $B$, presenting a pair of linear transformations $\R^n \xrightarrow{A} \R^l \xleftarrow{B} \R^m$ with a common target.  The *pullback* or *generalized intersection* of these two maps is defined to be the collection of pairs of vectors $(x, y) \in \R^n \times \R^m$ with $Ax = By$.  This, too, is easy enough to model in *Mathematica*: the `NullSpace` of the block matrix $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}A & -B\end{array}\right]$ splits into a block matrix itself $\left[\begin{array}{c}P \\ \hline Q \end{array}\right]$.  The matrices $P$ and $Q$ present the "largest nontrivial" maps into $\R^n$ and $\R^m$ respectively with the property that $AP = BQ$.

While the mathematics continues to make sense, both of these run into serious difficulties when $0$-dimensional vector spaces get involved.  This happens all the time in both situations (and, generally, in any situation where you might be applying `NullSpace` to a matrix with trivial kernel): because *Mathematica* models matrices as lists of lists (with some exceptions, like `SparseArray`s, which have to support conversion to lists of lists anyway), it has real trouble modeling an $(n \times 0)$-dimensional matrix.  For instance, `NullSpace[ IdentityMatrix[n]]` returns `{}`, which at first glance is reasonable enough but is totally unsuited for uniformly handling the above procedures.  The expression `{}` is not $(n \times 0)$-dimensional in any sense, and so matrix multiplication, transposition(, inversion in the case $n = 0$), and so on all balk at using this as input.

This is surmountable, of course, by riddling my *Mathematica* code with conditionals that check for this failure output and handle it separately.  This is uglier than it sounds (and it already sounds ugly); oftentimes this means passing around extra information to keep track of the `n` involved, since it's not recoverable from `{}`.

> **My question is:** Is there a cleaner solution than a sea of conditionals?  Is there an idiomatic way to model $(n \times 0)$- and $(0 \times n)$-dimensional matrices in *Mathematica*, ideally in a way that's near-seamlessly compatible with standard routines like `Times`, `Transpose`, `ArrayFlatten`, ...?

(P.S.: I eventually intend to offer this thing I'm writing as a package, and so I'd prefer not to modify the behavior of built-in functions directly.)

Comment: reminds me of a little article on the same issue by Carl de Boor with the title *An empty exercise* ([citation](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=122273), [pdf](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/234783851_An_empty_exercise/file/72e7e518b37f190414.pdf)).

Comment: What would the product of an n by 0 and a 0 by m matrix return?

Comment: It would produce the n × m matrix of all zeroes, of course.  You're asking for a matrix presentation of a map R^m --> R^n which factors through the vector space {0}, and there is only one of those: the zero map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little late, I guess, since I had similar ideas to both rm-rf and ybeltukov.

---

I would try using one head to represent an empty matrix, and define what `Dot` etc. means via [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagSetDelayed.html).  You can add error messages for mismatched dimensions in the [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) test -- you'll certainly need them.

```
ClearAll[emptyMatrix];

  (* this comes up in the product of an r x 0 times 0 x c empty matrices *)
emptyMatrix[r_Integer, c_Integer] /; r > 0 && c > 0 := ConstantArray[0, {r, c}];

 (* extend Dot *)
emptyMatrix /: 
  Dot[m1_emptyMatrix, m2_?MatrixQ] /; 
   Last[m1] == First@Dimensions[m2] := 
  emptyMatrix[First@Dimensions[m1], Last[m2]];
emptyMatrix /: 
  Dot[m1_?MatrixQ, m2_emptyMatrix] /; 
   Last@Dimensions[m1] == First[m2] := 
  emptyMatrix[First@Dimensions[m1], Last[m2]];
emptyMatrix /: 
  Dot[m1_emptyMatrix, m2_emptyMatrix] /; Last[m1] == First[m2] := 
  emptyMatrix[First[m1], Last[m2]];

  (* extend Transpose *)
emptyMatrix /: Transpose[emptyMatrix[r_, c_]] := emptyMatrix[c, r];

  (* extend scalar multiplication -- other uses of Times left as an exercise *)
emptyMatrix /: Times[k_?NumericQ, m_emptyMatrix] := m;

(* etc. *)
```

I think you have to define your own interfaces to some linear algebra functions.  For example, `NullSpace`:

```
Clear[nullSpace];
nullSpace[m_] := NullSpace[m] /. {} -> emptyMatrix[First@Dimensions[m], 0];
```

`ArrayFlatten` seems like it might take some work to get it right.

Examples:

```
nullSpace[IdentityMatrix[3]]
(*
   emptyMatrix[3, 0]
*)

RandomReal[1, {3, 3}].nullSpace[IdentityMatrix[3]]
(*
   emptyMatrix[3, 0]
*)

RandomReal[1, {2, 3}].nullSpace[IdentityMatrix[3]]
(*
   emptyMatrix[2, 0]
*)

emptyMatrix[4, 0].emptyMatrix[0, 3]
(*
   {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
*)

{{}}.emptyMatrix[0, 3]
(*
   {{0, 0, 0}}
*)

{{}, {}, {}}.emptyMatrix[0, 3]
(*
   {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
*)

RandomReal[1, {3, 2}].nullSpace[IdentityMatrix[3]]
(* Here an error message would be nice
   {{0.0973613, 0.422063}, {0.896662, 0.522105}, {0.357575, 0.980591}}.emptyMatrix[3, 0]
*)

Transpose[emptyMatrix[0, 3]]
(*
   emptyMatrix[3, 0]
*)

2 emptyMatrix[5, 0]
(*
   emptyMatrix[5, 0]
*)
```

Other problems might include extending `Map` and `Fold`.

---

I can add to rm-rf's answer that `ArrayFlatten` works with $n \times 0$ matrices of the form `{{}, {}, ..}`, but you're still left with the problem of $0 \times n$ matrices.

```
m1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}};
m2 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
m0 = {{}, {}};

ArrayFlatten[{{0, 0, m1}, {m2, m0, 0}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This might be helpful in working out how to extend `ArrayFlatten` to general empty matrices.

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is definition of your own types

```
ClearAll[nxo, oxn];
nxo /: Transpose[nxo[n_]] := oxn[n];
oxn /: Transpose[oxn[n_]] := nxo[n];
nxo /: A_ .nxo[n_] /; Dimensions[A][[2]] == n := nxo@Dimensions[A][[1]];
oxn /: oxn[n_].A_ /; Dimensions[A][[1]] == n := oxn@Dimensions[A][[2]];
```

Note the space between `A_` and `.nxo`. You can add much more rules for another built-in commands.

```
IdentityMatrix[{5, 10}].nxo[10]
```

> nxo[5]

Answer (score 6):

You can create $n\times 0$ matrices in *Mathematica* as follows:

```
nx0[n_Integer] := ConstantArray[{}, n]
Dimensions@nx0[10]
(* {10, 0} *)
```

This will also obey matrix multiplication (and perhaps a few other operations):

```
IdentityMatrix[10].nx0[10]
(* {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}} *)
```

However, I don't know of a good way to natively represent $0\times n$ matrices. Transposing the above will collapse all the nested empty lists to a single `{}`, which is not useful.

This doesn't go all the way for what you wanted, but perhaps it can be of some use.