# Redefine a function on certain values

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix

This question is related to [Zero-dimensional matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39522/zero-dimensional-matrices?rq=1), in particular to the answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39543/42722.

In Mathematica $0 \times n$-matrices are not well-defined, so I extended the definitions of `Dimensions`, `Dot`, `Transpose` ,`Join`, ... to a function `emptyMatrix[n]`, which should represent an $0 \times n$-matrix for $n\geq 0$.

For example, we have `Transpose[emptyMatrix[n]]=ConstantArray[{},n]` and so on. This works all quite well, except that `Transpose[ConstantArray[{},n]]` in Mathematica gives `{}`, so in this case I need to redefine (instead of simply extending) the function `Transpose` on $n \times 0$-matrices.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use system functions? Otherwise this will do
`transpose[expr_] := Transpose[expr];
transpose[list : {{} ..}] := emptyMatrix[Length[list]];`

Comment: aha, I didn't think of that.. thx! probably I don't need system functions. If Transpose is used in some other system function I'm using, then I could do the same trick again, I guess

Comment: The alternative is to `Unprotect` and use the same definition on `Transpose`. I won't make any promise on that not introducing weird bugs though =)